# Synchronizing GUI wallet issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I just downloaded the new GUI and completed the download of the blockchain for a local node, but for some reason the wallet is not syncing and after I restart the daemon and GUI, both of them say "synchronizing". It's been hours. Does it usually take that long?

[image]

How do I check the status of this synchronizing status? It is stuck here for hours after I restarted my computer and reloaded the GUI. I can't tell if it is frozen or if it's doing something. Before restarting I had a about 17371 blocks on the synchronizing wallet line, now it is back to the above screenshot. The daemon was completed before the restart.

Comment: Did you create a new wallet or restore one from seed? Can you provide a screenshot of the lower left status bars of the gui in your original question?

Comment: I created a new wallet

Comment: Your local daemon is probably not synchronized. That takes anywhere from a few hours to a few days depending on your computer. If you need an easier/faster setup, try simple mode where no local daemon is needed.

Comment: If I use the simple mode for "no local daemon" will I possibly lose privacy from what was described when I first installed the program that explained the 3 options?

Comment: Are you running them separately or just via the GUI? It sounds like, from the way you asked, you ran the daemon *separately*. Please clarify the steps you took. Also, is your hard drive a spinning HD or SSD?

Comment: Not sure. what I did was I ran monero-daemon, then I opened up the GUI. I have an SSD with 100MBPs connection.. It is working now, but very slow I am now at 17371 wallet blocks remaining. I guess I just have to wait?

Comment: 1) Just run the GUI, it starts the daemon. 2) make for certain it is storing the blockchain on your SSD and not some other HDD. With a normal broadband connection and syncing to SSD, the whole blockchain usually takes a few hours.